# Populate jQuery calendar with user timezone

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, timezone

I want to populate jQuery calendar with user timezone. Is there any solution in asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send all your DateTime info down to the client using [UTC format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), then you can use a library like [jsTimeZoneDetect](https://bitbucket.org/pellepim/jstimezonedetect/wiki/Home) to work out the difference.